# Cannot Deserialize Generic Type T Moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, moshi

Sorry if this is a basic question, but i'm new to Moshi.

So, I have a class with Generic Type Paramter as follows:

```
class BaseResponse<T> {
   @Json(name = "message")
   var message: String? = null
   @Json(name = "data")
   var data: T? = null
   @Json(name = "meta")
   var meta: JsonObject? = null
   @Json(name = "error")
   var error: ErrorResponse? = null
}
```

In GSON, this is done automatically and it works as long as i provide @SerializedName("data") and extends BaseResponse in my retrofit method. But it returns error with moshi as i could not deserialize BaseResponse. How can i fix this?

Comment: You'll need to create moshi adapter to do that conversion for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, how can i create this adapter? do i need to create adapter for every class?

Answer (score 4):

Both base class and class that replace generic type in code must be annotated with **@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)**. Please notice that the most important thing in order json to be converted correctly to a model class such as this, is to declare fields at base class as var and **NOT as val**. Please look the example below:

```
 @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
 class BaseResponse<T> {

   @Json(name = "message")
   var message: String? = null
   @Json(name = "data")
   var data: T? = null
   @Json(name = "meta")
   var meta: JsonObject? = null
   @Json(name = "error")
   var error: ErrorResponse? = null
}
```

Api example:

```
@GET("api/info")
suspend fun getInfo(): BaseResponse<Info>
```

Info:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Info(
    val language: String? = null,
    val profile: Profile? = null
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was using the val in the BaseResponse class. Now I am using the var and it's working fine.

Comment: You save the day...  Thanks for posting an answer

Answer (score 1):

In Moshi you have to explicitly declare your annotations as field annotations, like `@field:Json(name = "message")`

Comment: thank you for your response, is @field:Json(name = "data") different to @Json(name = "data")?

Comment: Yes, in a way. `@field:Json` = `@Json` but `@Json` != `@field:Json`. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets (Annotation use-site targets)
Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem